# Android: How to access data across all Activites?

Tags: android, memory, storage

I am searching for a possibility to store the user ID (received after login) in a way that all Activites have access to it.
If I understood it correctly a SharedPreference is only available for one specific Acitivty.

Which possibilites do I have to save the ID comprehensively?

Greetings,
oetzi

Comment: No. SharedPreferences is available for all activities :)

Comment: Really? Then I am doing probably anything wrong?! Do I have to take care of anything if I want to access the stored data in the seconds Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1: Create a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to hold your data (preferred)
- Option 2: Override [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and access the data using the context

Those are for application states which will be **non-persistent**, meaning that they're stored in memory and therefor will be lost, as soon as your application quits.

For persistent storage, use one of those.

- Option 1: Use the [`SharedPrefferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- Option 2: Use a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- Option 3: Use the [internal application memory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) (for private data)

For more ideas, see the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) article from the Android Docs.

Comment: I am often stumbling over the correct use of static... If I would use the singleton pattern, does every user have its own object with the individuell user ID? I assumed that there would be only one user ID for all users because of the static?!

Comment: @oetzi If you use a singleton, there is only one instance *per VM* (or application, if you will). Therefor, if you need multiple user ID's to be stored, make it a `List`.

Comment: okay thanks, at least my general assumption was correct ;-) Since I want to use precisely the user ID to identify the current user, using a static list with lot's of different user IDs seems not to be the right way. I would like to use the SharedPrefferences if it is possible to use them across different Activities. Could you have a look at my comment above (or below). Maybe I am using them in a wrong way?!

Comment: @oetzi Although I don't think you fully understood the singleton approach, for the documentation on [SharedPreferences, see the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). There should be everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

To put data:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("user_id", "THE USER ID HERE");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String userID = prefs.getString("user_id", null);
```

If the user id is a number you can use putInt or whatever the primitive data is.

Comment: That is what I did already. But how can I access the stored information from another activity?

Comment: I guess that I am doing anything wrong... How do I access the stored data within the seconds Activity? I am simply using: `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("id", "not there")` and I am only getting "not there"

Answer (score 0):

The SharedPreferences are accessible throughout you whole application. 
If you only need to store the data only for the runtime of the app, just declare it public static and you can access it from anywhere.